# Difference between にしたら /として/にとって

Tags: grammar, word-choice

As I understand it both にしたら and にとって mean "~ from the point of view of ~". What are the differences and if there is a similarity between either and として and is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand it both にしたら and にとって mean "~ from the point of view of ~". What are the differences and if there is a similarity between either and として and is the difference between them ?

As @Peri says, each of them means different.
**として** is basically '***as***': 先生{せんせい}**として**働{はたら}く (work as a teacher).

**にしたら** has the sense of conditional. Yes, you have it right; it means something like "***from someone's perspective.***" We would say ネコの身{み}**にしたら**いい迷惑{めいわく}というものだ. (From the perspective of the cat, it must be an annoyance.) We would also say ネコ**にしてみれば**迷惑な話だろう. Actually, many similar expressions are possible: にすれば, からしたら, の立場に立ってみれば, etc. But all these tend to sound rather informal except maybe の立場からすると.

**にとって** is, yes, '**for/to**' though we don't use this to mean 'made for'. We use this in, for example, 私**にとって**大切{たいせつ}な人です (S/He is important to me), or この街{まち}**にとって**観光産業{かんこうさんぎょう}は重要{じゅうよう}です (Tourism is important industry for this city), わが社**にとって** (For our company).